How to get “preferred” block size for efficient filesystem I/O - OS agnostic
I would like to know how to get the “preferred” block size for efficient filesystem I/O. I'm aware of of the below function https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/linux/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.st_blksize to get that info but it is linux specific. Is there a OS agnostic way to get this info?

you could create a trait with platform-specific implementations:
  trait BlockSizeExt {
    fn preferred_block_size(&self) -> u64;
}

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
impl BlockSizeExt for std::fs::Metadata {
    fn preferred_block_size(&self) -> u64 {
        use std::os::linux::fs::MetadataExt;
        self.st_blksize()
    }

    // Similar implementations for macOS, Windows, etc.
}

or
const DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE: u64 = 4096;  // Common block size for many filesystems

fn get_block_size(path: &std::path::Path) -> u64 {
    // Try platform-specific methods first
    #[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
    {
        if let Ok(metadata) = std::fs::metadata(path) {
            use std::os::linux::fs::MetadataExt;
            return metadata.st_blksize();
        }
    }
    
    // Fallback to default
    DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE
}

